# undefined reference to `yywrap`

Tags: c, gcc, flex-lexer

I have my lex file here.

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}

%%
stop    printf("Stop command received\n");
start   printf("Start command received\n");
%%
```

I compiled it using `flex`. But there's an error when I compile the `lex.yy.c` using `gcc`.
It says..

`: undefined reference to yywrap`

I used `gcc lex.yy.c -lfl` but there's still an error.
It says..

```
ld.exe: cannot find -lfl
```

Please help me to compile my `lex.yy.c` file.
Thank you so much.

Comment: sorry, my problem is `ld.exe: cannot find -lfl`. what should I do?

Comment: Did you try the other option from that question?

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches. The ones I recommend are.

Provide your own yywrap() function.

Since my compilers usually allow multiple source files, I prefer to define my own yywrap(). I'm compiling with C++, but the point should be obvious. If someone calls the compiler with multiple source files, I store them in a list or array, and then yywrap() is called at the end of each file to give you a chance to continue with a new file. NOTE: getNextFile() or compiler->getNextFile() are my own functions, not flex functions.

```
int yywrap() {
   // open next reference or source file and start scanning
   if((yyin = getNextFile()) != NULL) {
      line = 0; // reset line counter for next source file
      return 0;
   }
   return 1;
}
```

If building with C++ use:

```
extern "C" int yywrap() {
   // open next reference or source file and start scanning
   if((yyin = compiler->getNextFile()) != NULL) {
      line = 0; // reset line counter for next source file
      return 0;
   }
   return 1;
}
```

With older lex/flex, yywrap() was a macro, so to redefine it we had to do:

```
%{
#undef yywrap
%}
```

Potentially you could redefine a simple macro which would end scanning after a single file:

```
%{
#undef yywrap
#define yywrap() 1
%}
```

With newer Flex / POSIX lex, you can disable yywrap altogether at the command line:

```
flex --noyywrap
```

This works for other functions besides yywrap (--noyymore etc.)

Or put it in the options section.

```
%option noyywrap
/* end of rules */
%%
```

Where the general syntax of a lex file is:

```
Options and definitions
%%
Rules
%%
C code
```

Comment: thanks, I appreciate the answer. But the error's still there. 
`%option noyywrap` is already on the generated `lex.yy.c`

Comment: Is it in the options section (ie above the first %%) ? Did you try one  of the other options I suggested?